# How to Add a Custom Animation Transition using a TabView with PageTabViewStyle

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I would like to add a custom transition between pages. I have this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentPage = 0
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $currentPage) {
                Color.red
                    .tag(0)
                Color.yellow
                    .tag(1)
                Color.purple
                    .tag(2)
                Color.cyan
                    .tag(3)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: currentPage)

            Button(action: {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1 > 3 ? 0 : currentPage + 1
            }, label: {
                Text("Change Page")
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like the `.animation(.easeOut(duration: 0.3), value: currentPage)` doesn't make any difference in transitioning from one page to another in a `TabView` using `PageTabViewStyle`. The animation that I get is always the `default` animation. I want the page switch to be smooth.

On this gif we can see that page switch doesn't interpolate like an `easeOut` curve. Anything that I put in the `.animation` modifier doesn't affect the transition. Neither duration or curve type.

I already tried to use the `withAnimation` block inside the button action but doesn't affect the transition as well.

Has anyone being able to customize the page switch using a `TabView` in `SwiftUI`?

[image: This is a GIF that contains a page switch that doesn't interpolate with an easeOut curve]

Comment: Can you use a `ScrollView` with `scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)` instead? I think `ScrollView` supports custom animations.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried `ScrollView`, and the animations indeed works in conjuction with `ScrollReader` and `.scrollTo` method. The problem is that I would like to take advantage of `currentPage` binding and not rewrite this logic, because the final product its way more complex than the example that I gave above. If that is what I have to do to have a nice animation, so that's ok. I wish this API could work as I expected.

Comment: You can use the `scrollPosition` modifier to have a current tab binding. Are you supporting a version below iOS 17 perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I still need to support iOS 16, although I wasn't aware of this `scrollPosition` modifier, that's a good one, thanks! I could just ignore iOS 16 for now and make it work nice at least on the iOS 17 and above .